# Why is my form generating a KeyError instead of raising ValidationError from forms?

Tags: python, django, keyerror

I have a form that has three main fields which are required. These fields are ForeignKey fields. the second and third are dropdowns, the third being a dropdown that is dependent on the second field data. When I submit the form fully filled out, it works. If I submit the first and second field, with the third empty, when it should have something selected, it does raise the ValidationError, however when I submit the form with just the first field filled out, it creates this error, instead of raising the ValidationError

```
KeyError at /operations/enter-exit-area/
'work_area'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/operations/enter-exit-area/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'work_area'
Exception Location: operations\forms.py in clean, line 23
```

**models.py**

```
class WorkArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Station(models.Model):
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="stations")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedAuthModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number', 'modified_in', 'modified_out')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        emp_num = cleaned_data['employee_number']
        area = cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = cleaned_data['station_number']

        if area is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must select a work area")
        if Station.objects.filter(work_area=area).exists() and station is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must select a station")
```

**models.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    message = ''
    disable_enter = False
    disable_exit = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WarehouseForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
            area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
            station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

            if 'enter_area' in request.POST:
                # Logic ..

    else:
        form = WarehouseForm()

    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
        'disable_enter': disable_enter,
        'disable_exit': disable_exit
    })
```

Comment: because **`cleaned_data`** doesn't contain a Key named **`work_area`**

Comment: I tried checking from the clean() function but when I run in debugger it never even gets to it. I just returns after form.is_valid()

Comment: `area = cleaned_data['work_area']` → `area = cleaned_data.get('work_area')`